# A lot of "express routers" in a single Bookshelf transaction

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

Bookshelf transaction is working only in callback function. How i can do it?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  Bookshelf.transaction((trx) => {
    req.trx = trx;
    next();
  });     
});
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  // use req.trx 
});
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => { 
  // use req.trx 
});
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  req.trx.commit(); 
});
```

Comment: This probably is a stupid question as I don't know Bookshelf but can't you just store the variable? Like, you declare express, rooter and something like `trxValue = -1; `, properly set it in the first callback with `req.trx = trx; trxValue = trx` and then use that global variable elsewhere doing `req.trx = trxValue`?

Comment: It is can not help with trouble. Transaction auto run "commit" after end callback and resolve Promise.